# Array index out of bounds and causing error?

Tags: arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I know this is an easy fix but it is killing me. I have tried to look at other questions and cant find any that have helped. This is my last option to post here because I am running out of time to finish this program. This program reads numbers from a file and prints out the word vale of each digit ie. 30 : three zero, 150 : one five zero

the error shows out of bounds at the line of code

System.out.print(alsoWords[((int) digit - 0)] + " ");

```
    package main;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {

// can use String array instead of Map as suggested in comments
private static final String[] alsoWords = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};

public static void main(String args[]) //throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    Scanner fin = null;
 //           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("translates.txt"));
 //
 //           while (scanner.hasNextInt())
    {
        try {
            fin = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Brian2\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\main\\src\\main\\translate.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Error opening the file translates.txt");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        while (fin.hasNext()) {
            int i = 0;
            i ++;
            char[] chars = ("" + fin.nextInt()).toCharArray();

            System.out.print(String.valueOf(chars) + ": ");

            // for each digit in a given number
            for (char digit : chars) {
                System.out.println(i);
                System.out.print(alsoWords[((int) digit - 0)] + " ");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    fin.close();

}
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step through your code in the debugger. Inspect the values of each variable.

```
for (char digit : chars)
```

`digit` is a Unicode character.

```
(int) digit
```

You are getting the Unicode point of `digit`. For [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) characters this is the same as the ASCII value. For example, the ASCII value of `NUL` is zero. The ASCII value of the character `0` is `48`. Suppose the first character was a zero. You are getting:

```
48 - 0
```

Which is 48.

```
alsoWords[48]
```

is out of bounds. You want:

```
alsowords[(int)digit - (int)'0']
```

How to deal with characters before `'0'` is left as an exercise for the reader.